# Find table by name - Django

Tags: python, django, orm

How I can find table by name in code python?

Example:

```
class AlexAlex(models.Model):
    title =  models.CharField(max_length=255)
    message = models.TextField()
    dataMsg = models.DateField()
    fromMsg = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    readMsg = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and now I want to find the class name as it has some username.

Example in code:

```
UserLogged = "AlexAlex" or UserLogged = "Alex alex" + "s" // Example name user logged
Table = functionWhichFindTablebyName(UserLogged) // Find table by name 
Table.objects.get.all()
```

Can I do like this?I want that use for 'box mail users'.I have a lot of table and I don't wanna write manual in import/from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that this reflects a poorly implemented thing that needs a second though. It sounds like you are creating a table for each user, and storing there the messages for that user, when you should create a table `Message` related to `User`. That being said, if you want to retrieve an object (a table) from a module:

```
from any_app import models

getattr(models, "AlexAlex").objects.all()
```

Django also offers [ContentTypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/), which allows you to do the things you ask for without having to import the models. E.g.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

obj = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="any_app", model="alexalex")
obj.model_class().objects.all()
# Or p.get_all_objects_for_this_type(kwargs)
```

Comment: Ok, so you think the best way would be to create one table that will display all messages and in each option message, which user can read this message?

Comment: I don't know nothing about your app. It sounds that I would probably do `Message.objects.filter(user=AlexAlex)` or something like that. But I cannot know. There are legitimate uses for `ContentType` to exist, maybe your app needs it after all.

Comment: This is the standard message mail box. I just only need take all messages from base and display in site. But for example I add another line:                                                     
`toUserMsg = models.CharField(max_length=255)` and what now If message need send to more than one user?

Comment: If I understand correctly, "a user can have many messages, and the same message can be owned by many users" reflects a ManyToMany relationship. But that would mean that if a Message gets deleted/modified, it affects the other users. If each user should have exclusive control over all its messages without affecting the others, then it's a ManyToOne relationship but creating a copy of Message for each User (which you're doing anyways inserting the same message in different tables, I suspect).

Comment: The message can be read-only. Do you prefer the Many To Many method or does each user have a separate table with messages? Which will be better and more optimizing? Thanks for help.

Comment: It sounds (again, without knowin too much of your app) like ManyToMany would do. But beware that M2M is relatively complex. Django ORM is going to help you, but getting access to objects can be tricky if you never did it before. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/